# Elastcsearch NEST client is always using PUT http method instead of POST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to index my documents with ES NEST client and expect them to have unique Ids for indexed documents. For doing that I'm using pipeline processor in order to remove the Id field from my model.
However, Id always stored as 0 in ES side.

I noticed that my Index request is using PUT http method request which is probably indicates why Id not auto generated.
My question is how can I configure NEST client to use POST http method instead of PUT?

Comment: what version of NEST are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but you might want to disable Id inference globally (or for specific types) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html#_disabling_id_inference

```cs
WithConnectionSettings(x => x
    .DefaultMappingFor<MyOtherDTO>(m => m
        .DisableIdInference()
    )
).Expect(null).WhenInferringIdOn(dto);
```

```cs
WithConnectionSettings(x => x.DefaultDisableIdInference())
    .Expect(null).WhenInferringIdOn(dto);
```